# A string is saved every 20 seconds; is it faster to save it into a database or a text file?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms, file

I am backing up TextBox entries every 20 seconds. I am looking for the best place to save the text. The database that I am using is `SQL Server CE 3.5`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to write both and test for speed.  It's the only way to get a definite answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML Files approach is:
* Easier for you to use in your current application.
* do not require you to store data redundantly
* can be accessed via standard XML APIs
* Data is universally understandable and portable
* Slow and memory hungry
* do not allow advanced locking, synchronization and concurrency control
* do not have any support for transactions

Database approach is:
* Relatively complex to use in your current application.
* Data will have to be retrieved from XML files anyway
* You can use standard SQL with powerful querying facilities.
* Data retrieval is very fast
* advanced locking, synchronization and concurrency control mechanisms available
* Transactions allow you better control and reliability.

Answer (score 4):

Related to why you save that info

1.If you want to store it for a long time, use database.

2.If you remove saved data for short intervals, use file or xml.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the application.  If you are just saving this stuff to be referenced 20 seconds later and then garbaged I would go with xml but if you are creating a log of sorts that you'll want to reference long term I would go with a database.